# converting value returned from js function

Tags: javascript

The following js returns an error as below when trying to complete a conditional statement `if( asset_type.indexOf("true,false") >= 0  )`

I have tried to convert asset_type to string... and all fail

**Error**:

> asset_type.get is not a function

the folowing code does return

```
console.log("Asset Type (row " + i + "): " + asset_type );
```

> Asset Type (row 12): true,false

**Code:**

```
$("#myTable_asset").children("tbody").children("tr").each(function (i) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var my_td = $this.children("td");
    var second_col = my_td.eq(1);
    var third_col = my_td.eq(2);
    second_col.find("input[type=text]").val(function(i, val) {
        return val.replace(/\$|,/g, '');
    });

    var asset_value =   second_col.find("input[type=text]").val();
    var asset_type = third_col.find(":checkbox").map(function(_, el) { return el.checked }).get()

    console.log("Asset Type (row " + i + "): " + asset_type );

    try {
        if ( '' != asset_type)
        {

            console.log("Asset Cost (row " + i + "): " + parseFloat(asset_value));
            console.log("Asset Type (row " + i + "): " + asset_type );

            if( asset_type.indexOf("true,false") >= 0  )
            {
                capex_value += parseFloat(asset_value);
            }

            if(asset_type.get().indexOf("false,true") >= 0  )
            {
                opex_value += parseFloat(asset_value);
            }

        }
    }

    catch(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
});
```

a print out of third_col.html() gives the following:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal ui-corner-all">
    <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ">
        <div class="ui-checkbox ui-mini">
            <label for="asset_allocation_capex_19" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-checkbox-off ui-first-child">
                Capex
            </label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="asset_allocation_capex_19" id="asset_allocation_capex_19" data-mini="true">
        </div>                                                                                                                              
        <div class="ui-checkbox ui-mini">
            <label for="asset_allocation_opex_19" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-checkbox-on ui-btn-active ui-last-child">
                Opex
            </label>
           <input type="checkbox" name="asset_allocation_opex_19" id="asset_allocation_opex_19" data-mini="true" checked="">
        </div>                                                                                                                          
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asset_type is an array of [true, false].
You cant do `get()` or `indexOf('true,false')`.
You can do:

```
var first = asset_type[0], scond = asset_type[1];
if(first=== true && second === false){...}
else if(first=== false && second === true){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you forgot that you already used get() on jquery elements here:

```
var asset_type = third_col.find(":checkbox").map(function(_, el) {
return el.checked }).get()
```

Just check your code.